# Nearly Optimal Sparse Walsh-Fourier Tranform

Tags: ds.algorithms, fourier-analysis

In the recent paper: [Nearly Optimal Sparse Fourier Transform[Haitham Hassanieh, Piotr Indyk, Dina Katabi, Eric Price]](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2501v1), the authors show an $O(k \log n)$-time algorithm for the problem of computing the discrete Fourier transform of an $n$-dimensional signal that has at most $k$ non-zero Fourier coefficients.

Is there a similar result for the Walsh-Fourier transform (or is it possible to use the same algorithm for a multidimensional DFT of size $2^n$) ?

Comment: Have you asked the authors about this? They may have a quick answer for you.

Comment: That's a good idea. I will ask and update in case I get an interesting answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the quoted paper itself summarizes in its introduction,

> The past two decades have witnessed significant advances in sublinear sparse Fourier algorithms. The first such algorithm (for the Hadamard transform)

(which is what you are looking for)

> appeared in [KM91](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103466) (building on [GL89](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=73010)). Since then, several sublinear sparse Fourier algorithms for complex inputs were discovered [Man92, GGI+02, AGS03, GMS05, Iwe10, [Aka10](http://www.colt2010.org/papers/005akavia.pdf), HIKP12].

Some of the quoted papers (e.g. [Aka10](http://www.colt2010.org/papers/005akavia.pdf)) give similar results for Fourier transforms over all Abelian groups.

Comment: I believe that these papers deal with a sparse approximation of a general function, while I'm interested in (efficient) exact computation of a sparse function.

Comment: There are sparse Fourier approximation algorithms, that guarantee to recover the signal exactly, if it is indeed $k$-sparse. E.g. [GGI+02] http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=509933 talks about this explicitly.